# Sharp develop in ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, compilation

Is it possible to compile C# in ubuntu using sharpdevelop?
I am searching for an alternative for monodevelop

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is wrong with [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) that makes you search for an alternative?

Comment: SharpDevelop only works on Windows.

Comment: Nothing wrong but i am searching ide with more productive environment
 monodevelop is the unique ide foe c# in linux :(

Comment: @why it cant compile in linux?

Comment: I mean it is an opesource ide then why it impossible to compile in linux
sorry if am wrong

Comment: @BoltClock: According to http://monodevelop.com/Download , it's available for Linux, Windows and OS X.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: That's MonoDevelop, not SharpDevelop.

Comment: @Aboobacker Mk: SharpDevelop is open source, but it's built on the .NET Framework, so it will only work on Windows. Just because something is open source doesn't necessarily mean it has to run on Linux, as much as we all wish it did.

Comment: Aha. I see you were responding to the question, not my comment below it. Apologies.

Comment: Q: I mean it is an opensource ide then why it impossible to compile in linux sorry if am wrong.  A: Sorry, you're wrong :)  SharpDevelop is Windows-only ...

Comment: Why mono cant do it?
It is the open source implementaion of .net framework(as per their website)

means mono parially implementing .net?

Comment: @Aboobacker Mk: Yes but SharpDevelop uses components that are only supported on Windows, so those components won't be able to compile on other OSes because they're missing. Mono isn't a .NET port for non-Windows OSes.

Comment: Why doesn't anyone just answer the question?  You all seem to know the answer, so post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you'll need to use MonoDevelop. SharpDevelop is Windows-only and not supported on Ubuntu.

But you can [help with the MonoDevelop project](http://monodevelop.com/Developers) to make it better.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know SharpDevelop is using a lot of win32 calls, this is why is not 100% percent a .net application and runs only on windows.

It would be possible to run under wine, the information on WineHQ AppDb is very old about it.

I had try with wine debian version 1.0.1-3.5 and it was *not* possible to install dotnet40 using winetricks, when try to install the msi installer for SharpDevelop it fails with the message that "This setup requires the .NET 4.0 Full Framework to be installed"

I'll try using a newer version of wine and comment here what happend.

OT: MonoDevelop is a great solution, it could be even better if has one competitor in the Linux environment.

Comment: I had try to install SharpDevelop under wine 1.4~rc3, it fails.I was able to install dotnet40 (with some bugs and help from WineHQ AppDb and the latest version of winetricks). The msi installer of SharpDevelop runs but it was not possible to complete the installation due MSI problems registering assemblies). Maybe it would be possible to run with other installer or compiling SharpDevelop under wine using MS Net framework or Mono)